# Where should I install with write access under user access control?

Tags: installation

I need to install to a location that is accessible to all users on a PC and also has write access under User Access Control (Vista and Windows 7).  Initially I was installing to the program files directory but this does not have write access under UAC.  I am currently installing under the app files directory but this only installs for a single user with admin rights.  I can't create a shortcut to it for all users.  Where should I install to?

Thanks in advance for your help.